# Пример нейронных сетей C++

Tags: c++, нейронные-сети

Где я могу найти примеры программ использующие нейронные сети на языке C++?

Comment: И мне тоже было бы интересно. Найдёте - выкладывайте.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Как раз на днях я занимался чтением статей о простейших нейронных сетях, и по пути набросал свою **простейшую** сеть. Данная сеть была предназначена для распознавания цифр на картинках - классическая задача в большинстве статей рунета:) Однако саму структуру нейронов старался делать независимой от задачи, и по-моему получилось довольно показательно. Надеюсь пояснений в комментариях будет достаточно. Классы представляют части искусственного нейрона, и называются соответственно

Заголовочный файл:

```
class Neuron
{

public:

/*Аксон - выходная часть нейрона, которая передает состояние
 нейрона дальше, обработанное функцией активации*/
    class Akson{
    public:
        float getSignal();//Функция активации
        Neuron *ownerNeuron;
    };

/*Дендрит - одна из входных линий нейрона. Содержит весовой коэффициент.
В данной архитектуре каждый дендрит содержит указатель на предшествующий ему
аксон, с которого он и получает сигнал.*/
    class Dendrit{
    public:
        float weight = 0.1;
        Akson *inputAkson;
    };


    Neuron();
/*Вектор, содержащий входные дендриты, т.к. их может быть разное количество*/
    std::vector<Dendrit> dendrits;
    Akson akson;
/*Суммирующая функция, которая суммирует(В самом простом случае)
входные сигналы*/
    virtual float kernelFunction();
/*Состояние нейрона*/
    float value;
};
```

Файл реализации собственно реализует функции нейрона и аксона. Функция нейрона объявлена виртуальной, чтобы ее можно было переопределить для каждого слоя нейронов.

Вот код реализации:

```
#include "neuron.h"
#include <cmath>

/*В качестве функции активации используется т.н. сигма-функция,
которая обрабатывает сигнал, полученный суммирующей функцией нейрона*/
float Neuron::Akson::getSignal()
{
    return (1 / (1 + exp(-(ownerNeuron->kernelFunction())))) ;
}

/*Конструктор устанавливает для в качестве нейрона-владельца
аксона свой объект*/
Neuron::Neuron()
{
    akson.ownerNeuron = this;
}

/*Нейрон запрашивает сигнал у каждого своего дендрита,
тем самым обращаясь к аксонам нейронов предыдущего слоя,
которые в свою очередь обращаются к своим нейронам и.т.д,
то есть сбор сигналов идет цепочкой от самого первого слоя*/
float Neuron::kernelFunction()
{
    float result(0.);
    for(Dendrit d : dendrits){
        result += d.inputAkson->getSignal() * d.weight;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Далее идет определение класса самой нейронной сети, состоящей, собственно, из нейронов:

```
class KohonenNet
{
public:

/*Создание подвида нейрона: входной нейрон, который только
передает входной сигнал дальше*/
    class InputNeuron : public Neuron{
    public:

        float kernelFunction(){
            return value;
        }

    };

    KohonenNet();
    vector<Neuron*> inNeurons;
    vector<Neuron> outNeurons;
    int handle(QImage);

private:
/*Функция обучения нейрона*/
    void study(Neuron &n, QImage pic);

/*Картинки с цифрами для обучения*/
    QString names[9] = {"0.bmp", "1.bmp", "2.bmp", "3.bmp","4.bmp","5.bmp","6.bmp","7.bmp", "8.bmp"};
    const uint numNumbers = 9;
};
```

Реализация функций сети уже решает конкретную задачу, занимает много строк кода и несет мало информации об устройстве самой сети, поэтому ее я не привожу.

П.С. Надеюсь, мои наработки кому-то помогут разобраться:)